# Map console key combination to single key press

Tags: linux, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, tty

I want to map (for example) the combinations:

Windows + Left == Home

`man setkeycode` seems to only talk about single key mappings.

How would I go about doing this in a Linux virtual terminal?

I'm running Manjaro, based on Arch.

Comment: maybe this may help ... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165124/autohotkey-equivalent#165143

Comment: @jsotola Sadly not. In your link: IronAHK has been discontinued and works by running scripts. // `autokey` is an X11 application, and as such will not function 100% on distributions that default to using Wayland instead of Xorg.

// `xodotool` is for X.